# Blank Canvas Page for iFrame App

Tags: facebook, iframe, canvas

I'm working on an iframe style app that pulls the facebook optimized page available at http://store.starrco.com/?store_mode=facebook. I've done other, admittedly much simpler, iframe apps before without issue but though I've configured this one more or less the same when I try to view the canvas url it remains blank.

My settings can be seen here: http://www.abstraktmg.com/clients/starrco/starrcofbsettings.jpg

I've tried a few different permutations of this with the same results, this is the most complete setup though and most closely matches the settings template I was given.

This page is being generated by Webasyst's shop-script, which is specifically supposed to support this.  The obvious answer then is to contact their support which I did, but after assuring them that my app settings matched their template, they said I needed to contact Facebook support and this is as close as I could find to any proper support system.

Answer (score 0):

I checked both http and https versions of store.starrco.com/?store_mode=facebook and both worked outside of facebook.

However, there may be some framebusting code which might prevent the site from being loaded in an iframe. And I see that your settings appear to be missing the app domain entry.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, especially in Chrome and Firefox. The problem is, when the user is surfing with https on Facebook, the https Version of the iframe is called. But the browser do not show invalid certificate problems until you to right click page information.

You need to have a signed SSL cert by a CA trusted in the browser.

If the user has accepted it without the iframe - outside of Facebook, it works.